# Custom topLayoutGuide length in container view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, autolayout

Say for example, I have made a custom container view controller resembling a `UINavigationController`, but it has 2 navigation bars in the top.

Then, in child view controllers I use autolayout, and I of course want content to begin below the second navigation bar.

To achieve this automatically, I need to set the top layout guide to the height of the two navigation bars combined.

I assumed that we could just override the `topLayoutGuide`-property, but whatever I do, the `topLayoutGuide` function never gets called in either my custom container view controllers or the child view controllers.

So this means that `topLayoutGuide` is basically a worthless property, working ONLY with Apple's own container view controllers?

Please tell me I'm wrong!

Answer (score 7):

Reading through the docs on this, the `topLayoutGuide` property is `(readonly)`, and it's length attribute is also `(readonly)`. In addition to that, it states:

> A view controller within a container view controller does not set this
>   property's value. Instead, the container view controller constrains
>   the value to indicate:
>
> - The bottom of the navigation bar, if a navigation bar is visible
> - The bottom of the status bar, if only a status bar is visible
> - The top edge of the view controller’s view, if neither a status bar nor navigation bar is visible

Those three scenarios imply to me that it's probably not customizable, although I'd love to be proved wrong. Seems like a great use case for this functionality.

Comment: Yes, the weird thing is that it makes sense to override a readonly property in a subclass though. Something fishy happens in the runtime since the overridden method never even gets called...

Comment: UIKit classes rarely call their own accessors

Comment: The underlying issue here is that there is considerable magic in the topLayoutGuide. It cannot be replicated by just implementing UILayoutSupport. Under the hood these are UIView's... that's how they work with AutoLayout. In iOS9 there are new methods on the guides that would be extremely difficult to replicate in a custom subclass.